# Problems installing virtualenv on windows 10

Tags: python, virtualenv, windows-10

This is for school, I'm learning python, and I can't keep on going because I need to install some stuff that I just can't figure out how to get working.

I have installed python 2.7.10 and I've installed "pip".

I ran this command in CMD under administrator privileges:

```
C:\Users\randomrandom\Downloads\virtualenv-13.1.2>python setup.py install
```

This gave me:

```
Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for virtualenv==13.1.2
Finished processing dependencies for virtualenv==13.1.2
```

Here is the problem, when I try to run this command:

```
python -m virtualenv myenv
```

I get this:

```
C:\Users\randomrandom>python -m virtualenv myenv
New python executable in myenv\Scripts\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 22:     ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: The executable myenv\Scripts\python.exe is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'c:\\users\\*****\xe6r' (should be   u'c:\\users\\****\xe6r\\myenv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
Note: some Windows users have reported this error when they installed Python    for "Only this user" or have multiple versions of Python installed. Copying the    appropriate PythonXX.dll to the virtualenv Scripts/ directory may fix this   problem.
```

I've tried google, i've contacted my teacher, I have no idea what to do. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance and sorry if it's not well enough explained, I'm in over my head here.

PS: The "xe6r" in the path stuff is because I have a letter thats not common in my username, aka "æ".

Answer (score 0):

I got it working - I had to delete my old microsoft account and create a new user without any special characters in it!

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 22:     ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is what caused the problem.